# Al intentar copiar un fichero en Java con InputStream y PrintStream, me deniega el acceso

Tags: java

Estoy practicando lo que es InputStream y PrintStream para copiar y pegar ficheros con Java, pero por alguna razón me niega el acceso al directorio que quiero acceder; soy administrador así que dudo que sea eso.

```
public static class File{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Rfile("C:\\Java\\hola.txt","C:\\copia");
        }
        public static void Rfile(String fileIn, String fileOut){
            try {
                InputStream source = new FileInputStream(fileIn);
                byte[] datos = source.readAllBytes();
                source.close();

                PrintStream destiny = new PrintStream(fileOut);
                destiny.write(datos);
                destiny.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception " + e);
                System.out.println(fileIn);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: SImplemente usa como destino otra carpeta que no sea directamente C y te funcionará. Por ejemplo, `"C:\\Java\\copia.txt"`.  Para poder escribir directamente en C, debes ejecutar el programa como administrador, no basta que tu seas administrador. Si ejecutas eclipse como admin te funcionará.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, inicié como administrador, de igual manera no me deja, pero ya encontré el problema, y es que en la carpeta donde quiero pegar el archivo también debo colocar el nombre del archivo que quiero copiar y pegar, es decir que en fileOut debe ir **C:\\copia\\hola.txt**